# how to hide vertical nav on click and display the corresponding content ( Navigation on mobile site with back button)

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a mobile website, which is built as a single page application. I'm using angular to create a vertical menu, I want to hide the menu on menu item clicked and display its content container with a back button to go back to the menu.

first I have the main component with the menu and content container next to each other

main-component.html

```
 <div class="container">


  <div class="col-md-3 col-12 menu-container">
    <app-menu-container></app-menu-container>

  </div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-12"> 
  <app-content-container></app-content-container>
</div>
</div>
```

menu.component.html to loop over menu items and display them

```
<div *ngFor="let menuItem of menu">
           <app-menu-item [menuItem]="menuItem"> </app-menu-item>       
       </div>
```

menuItem.component that displays every menuItem. on item clicks, a subject will fire to open the corresponding content-container component

in the content-container component, I subscribed to get the item to open the content container
content-container.component.ts

```
  subscribeToOpenContainer() {
    this.subscriptionToOpenContainer = this.menuService.openMenuItemContainer.subscribe((menuItem) => {
      this.menuItem = menuItem;
    }
    );
  }
```

content-container.html

```
<ul>
      <li>
        <a class="document-type-icon"><i></i></a>


      <div class="text-container">
        <p class="document-name"></p>
        <p class="last-update-date"> Last update date:</p>

        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="action-icons-container">

        <a class="delete-and-edit-icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

        <a> <i class="fa fa-edit delete-and-edit-icon> </i>
        </a>

      </div>
    </li>
<ul/>
```

I want the menu that is a single component to hide when a menu item is active and the content container is displayed with a back button to get back to the menu.

current approach [image: current implemented approach]

what I want to achieve on mobile screen size

[image: when click on menu item]

[image: this should be displayed on top of the menu]

Comment: Please update your question with actual code as this code will not give you any output in angular.... Also i have some questions, 1) Where did you bind click on your items? 2) Where is back button? 3) On clicking are you changing route?

Comment: If possible make a stackblitz... As your requirements are so simple, we would be more than happy to help you. But without understanding your code we can't help you

Comment: on clicking, I'm not changing the route , I'm firing a subject that will send the clicked item to the content container that will open on item clicks

Comment: I don't have a back button I want to create one and i prefer if I can accomplish this with some HTML and CSS because what I have right now is the menu inline with the content container which is perfect on desktop screen but in a mobile screen  I want them to be on top of each other with a back button to toggle between them

Comment: https://petershamnurseries.com/ check this website vertical menu on mobile  size, I want the same approach

Comment: i updated my  code please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using simple *[ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)* if you want to hide the sidebar using a click of button. If you want to hide the sidebar on clicking anywhere, you can use *[HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)*.

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])onClick(event) { });
```

You can get id of the element clicked using *event.target.id*. Use *if* logic to check which item was clicked and open the sidebar if not open already, and if it is open you can hide it by simply adding or remove css to the *DOM*.